# Direction of Meteors

Tags: amateur-observing, meteor

Do meteors always streak in the same direction? While I know it's not likely to be exactly the same direction, but generally speaking. Would one say meteors always travel, for example, east to west?

Comment: Related: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/do-meteorites-streak-across-the-sky-in-the-same-direction

Answer (score 3):

Not in general, but sometimes there is a dominant direction.
When the Earth passes through a stream of debris from a comet or asteroid,
a
[meteor shower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_shower)
occurs, and those meteors appear to come from a point in the sky called the radiant.
Since the parent bodies have different orbits, different shower radiants appear in different parts of the sky.
For example, the Geminid radiant culminates earlier in the night than most, and the Perseid radiant is well north of the Ecliptic.
As the Earth can encounter meteors from any direction at any time, there are usually a few sporadic meteors unrelated to any active radiant.
Meteor observers have identified some
[not quite random](http://www.skyandtelescope.com/astronomy-blogs/explore-night-bob-king/random-meteors-arent-random02112015/)
directions for these.

Comment: thanks for that incredibly interesting link, MikeG - good one