# Meteor shower shooting stars

Tags: observational-astronomy

Shooting stars are actually meteors falling down on the surface of earth. How come some of them appear shooting up and not down?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1866/do-meteorites-streak-across-the-sky-in-the-same-direction Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_(meteor_shower)

Comment: Perspective.  It's all about viewing angle and lack of altitude reference.

Answer (score 1):

Shooting stars are indeed meteors falling down, but consider this: meteors which are part of a meteor shower actually appear to come from a point in the sky called the *radiant point*:
[google image](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=imgres&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiItuubkYLgAhWZV30KHV-9Dn8QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRadiant_(meteor_shower)&psig=AOvVaw0lP8KGKheVCSl9wC0P6qp_&ust=1548272112613916)

Since you're looking upwards, you may be looking straight at the radiant point, and therefore the meteors are 'radiating' away from that point in all directions; not only 'downwards' towards the horizon, but 'upwards' from your point of view.

You can see that, even for a meteor which is not part of a shower, it's just as likely for a meteor to be going 'upwards' across the sky, as it is to be going 'downwards'.